# Mailto link in a message with a subject line not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

I am trying to set a href of a tag using java script for making that tag open a dialog to send a mail.

```
var ancHref = "mailto:abc@abc.com "?"subject=Blank filter"+" "+'<%=QWebUtility.GetAppSettings().GetSetting("CompanyName") %>';
$("#divMessageBody").append("<a href=" + ancHref + "/>");
```

but something is going wrong can you tell me how to append a subject that could be dynamic in nature that i am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours variable is wrong:

```
var ancHref = "mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=Blank filter"+'<%=QWebUtility.GetAppSettings().GetSetting("CompanyName") %>';
$("#divMessageBody").append("<a href=" + ancHref + "/>");
```

You typed too much `"`

Answer (score 1):

one question is: are you doing this script externally or within the page? by your example, i think you are on the page. try changing to this

```
var ancHref = 'mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=Blank filter <%=QWebUtility.GetAppSettings().GetSetting("CompanyName") %>';
```

try this method of creating an element also:

```
var ancHref = 'mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=Blank filter <%=QWebUtility.GetAppSettings().GetSetting("CompanyName") %>';
var mylink = $(document.createElement('a'));
mylink.attr('href',anchref);
$("#divMessageBody").append(mylink);
```